# Raw HTML with Laravel and send paramaters/var

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement the [KeeWeb HTML file](https://github.com/keeweb/keeweb/tree/gh-pages) to my Laravel project.

I've tried to just add it to a blade file (e.g. `keeweb.blade.php`) and then using `return view('keeweb');` and I'm getting the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')'`

However, I've also opened the HTML file with my browser and it works fine, so it seems that Blade is parsing something it shouldn't be. Fine.

So next I tried to just make a test blade file, and in that just `@include('keeweb')` and then rename `keeweb.blade.php` to `keeweb.php` and I get the same.

So next I tried to simply `return view('keeweb'); //keeweb.php` with the same error.

I need to parse some sort of variable because I need to change the head of the document so I cannot just `File::get()`

Comment: Some `code` would be useful. How do you expect us to resolve your error without looking at code? Please post the code of your keeweb.blade.php, routes.php and your controller method that returns the view

Comment: I have provided the code. The keeweb.blade.php is the index.html in the link that I provided, and in my routes it's simply `return view('keeweb');`...

Comment: Try `return view('keeweb')->render();`

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen it shows a blank page with the same error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: @Nathan That looks like a javascript error. Is this error showing up in your console?

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen Not if I go to the HTML file directly, but with laravel, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there are multiple occurrences of `{{` in that file which Blade is trying to parse out.

I don't think you want to rename it to have only `.php` extension though.  Try keeping it keeweb.blade.php and when you include it, try the following...

```
@verbatim
    include('keeweb')
@endverbatim
```

Or even placing the `@verbatim` and `@endverbatim` inside the actual keeweb file at the top and bottom respectively, then you should be able to include it just like any other blade file.

Comment: It just shows a blank page when I wrap the source in `verbatim`